# Magical Record relationship return empty objects

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

There are two types of objects in my model - lets say `Kid` and `Parent`. I get them from server in iOS app in JSON like this:

```
{
  "kids": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "parents": [
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parents": [
        {
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, `Kid` have a `To-Many` relation to `Parent` object. I'm using Magical Record to store the date, and I have this relationship in Core Data Model to be able to get `kid.parents` objects.

When getting them from server, I am using this code:

```
for (NSDictionary *kidDict in objects)
        {
            NSNumber *oid = kidDict[@"id"]; // i'm using 'oid' in Obj-C when there is a need to use 'id' keyword
            Kid *kid = [Kid MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"oid" withValue:oid];
            if (kid == nil)
            {
                kid = [Kid MR_createEntity];
            }

            [kid updateFromDictionary:kidDict];
            [self updateParentsFromArray:kidDict[@"parents"] forKid:kid];
         }

         [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];


// ...

+ (void)updateParentsFromArray:(NSArray *)parents forKid:(Kid *)kid
{
// clearing current relationship
    NSSet *kidParents = [kid.kidParents copy];
    for (Parent *parent in kidParents)
    {
        [kid removeParentsObject:parent];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *parentDict in *parents)
    {
        NSNumber *oid = parentDict[@"id"];
        Parent *parent = [Parent MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"oid" withValue:oid];
        if (!parent)
        {
            parent = [Parent MR_createEntity];
        }
        [parent updateFromDictionary:parentDict]; // updating current object to catch all server changes for it
        [kid addParentsObject:parent];
    }
}

// Kid and Parent updating method

- (void)updateFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [dictionary mutableCopy];

    if (dict[@"id"]) self.oid = dict[@"oid"];
}
```

However, when I want to get `kid.parents`, it return me the array of empty objects. So for the first kid it returns one `Parent` with `oid == nil`, for the second kid it returns two `Parent`, both with `nil` properties. I simplified code for better readability, there are a lot of other properties in both objects, and all of them are nil.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong with saving? I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555166/coredata-returning-set-with-empty-objects), but it seems that my classes are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think this block of code actually does anything...

```
// clearing current relationship
NSSet *kidParents = [kid.kidParents copy];
for (Parent *parent in kidParents)
{
    [kid parent];
}
```

If you want to clear the relationships, you can just nil the to many side and everything will be disconnected. However, the data is not deleted unless you explicitly delete it. Look for the `-MR_deleteEntity` method to help you out there.

Second, I prefer to use `parent.kid = kid` syntax, rather than `[kid addParentsObject:parent]` when using a one-to-many relationship. It makes things a bit easier to read.

Third, there is no need to create a mutableCopy of your data dictionary in your updateFromDictionary method.

Fourth, the actual problem is likely that you're not passing in the proper dictionary subset into the updateFromDictionary method. It looks like you're just passing in the top level dictionary and not the parent specific info. You can tell this because you're still getting non-nil objects, but no data. The if-check on the data is a giveaway that data isn't contained in the dictionary being passed in.

On a side note, I will mention that MagicalRecord already has import code written for you. All you need to do is map the source data to the CoreData model. These mappings reside (currently) in the Entity Model file (the visual entity editor) in the user info dictionary. I suggest taking a look a the (brief) [instructions I wrote on CocoaismyGirlfriend.com](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/).

Comment: `[kid parent]` is clearly a mistake of mine, should be `[kid removeParentsObject...]`, edited. Thank you for second note, I'll think about it. Third one - I should had this line deleted in question - in real code I delete all NSNull objects there. Not necessary, since I'll look at MagicalRecord mapping as you've suggested. Hmmm, I'll check if I pass the right dictionaries, but I am sure they are correct too. Thank you for suggestions